# Installing dotnet-cli error

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation

I'm trying to install dotnet-cli in Arch linux with yaourt and there was a step of the way that it couldn't verify the authenticity of the libcurl-openssl-1.0 package so I did `gpg --recv-keys 5CC908FDB71E12C2` as instructed in the [comments](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/libcurl-openssl-1.0/) in the Arch Linux repository that worked but after that the coreclr didn't build because it couldn't copy a file so I tried manually that threw an error saying that I do not have sufficient space amount that I actually have and only around 1% of inodes are been used. At first when I tried to copy the file it said that I didn't have authorization access but wasn't able to reproduce this error anymore. I see that there's a dot in the path he's trying to copy (`tmp/yaourt-tmp-rinaldi/aur-dotnet/src/coreclr-1.1.2/bin/Product/Linux.x64.Release/./crossgen`) the file isn't that an issue? I shouldn't use sudo for yaourt should I?

```
CMake Error at src/tools/crossgen/cmake_install.cmake:36 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot copy file
  "/tmp/yaourt-tmp-rinaldi/aur-dotnet/src/coreclr-1.1.2/bin/obj/Linux.x64.Release/src/tools/crossgen/crossgen"
  to
  "/tmp/yaourt-tmp-rinaldi/aur-dotnet/src/coreclr-1.1.2/bin/Product/Linux.x64.Release/./crossgen".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/tools/cmake_install.cmake:37 (include)
  src/cmake_install.cmake:53 (include)
  cmake_install.cmake:44 (include)

  make: *** [Makefile:118: install] Error 1
Failed to build coreclr components.
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
==> ERROR: Makepkg was unable to build dotnet.
==> Restart building dotnet ? [y/N]
```

df -i output:

```
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
dev              752469    438   752031    1% /dev
run              753579    768   752811    1% /run
/dev/sda3       3662848 220787  3442061    7% /
tmpfs            753579    143   753436    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            753579     13   753566    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            753579  52000   701579    7% /tmp
tmpfs            753579     18   753561    1% /run/user/120
tmpfs            753579     62   753517    1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda2      57030444 542814 56487630    1% /mnt
```